# Recommendation for Wireless earbud suitable for dynamic sports

Tags: wireless, earphones

I want to know which earbud is best suited for dynamic sports, imagine gymnastics  handstand or high bar jumping.
the characteristics that i'm looking for is high-quality, durability and stability(something that doesn't drop)

Comment: This is going to be hard to answer as what fits your ear may not fit all ears.

Comment: well some earphones fit all lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you get the Jaybird X3. These earbuds come with multiple tips and fins in the box to make sure they stay in your ears. The X3s are wireless and can last up to 8 hours on a charge. The audio sounds great, there is a lot of bass and it can be tweaked with the Jaybird Mysound app to suit your needs. These earbuds are a bit expensive at 130 USD on Amazon but well worth the price.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01M7NCT5O](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M7NCT5O)

Just in case you like your specs.
https://www.jaybirdsport.com/en-us/x3-bluetooth-headphones/details-specs.html